# Image and tabbing: Best way to compose them side-by-side?

Tags: graphics, environments, tabbing

I have a template that currently uses the following tabbing environment:

```latex
\begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{2.75cm}\=\kill
    \textbf{Name:}\>\textit{John Doe} \\
    \textbf{Student ID:}\>\textit{c1234567} \\
    \textbf{Contact Number:}\>\textit{+01 234 567 890} \\
    \textbf{Contact Email:}\>\textit{John.Doe@email.com}
\end{tabbing}
```

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of rendered latex code]

Note that I have other stuff in place, causing the styling changes.

The idea of this block is that it is left-aligning the keywords and values. This can be done in other environments, but due to older/original use, and the fact that I am only using this for text, I decided it was perfectly fine as a tabbing environment. Though, there is no real reason for it to remain over another option.

So, I want to insert a small logo to the left side of this whole section, but I am not sure what the "best" approach to this is. That is, this whole section will move across (rightwards), and a square image/logo will be inserted into the left-side space.

Should I replace this whole environment in place of something else? I hope to avoid floats if possible due to the nature of this document. With that said, I know there are options with wrap figures, for example. Or alternatively, would it be better/easier to use Tikz?

Can you please show me alternative/better approaches to solving my problem? Primarily because, in the future, there may be changes, additions, or alterations, and I do not want to do something that is not flexible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it is not entirely clear (to me) what result of code you are after. So I guessing about this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X >{\bfseries}l>{\itshape}l}
\multirow{4}{22mm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}}
    &   Name            &   John Doe        \\
    &   Student ID:     &   c1234567        \\
    &   Contact Number: &   +01 234 567 890 \\
    &   Contact Email:  &   John.Doe@uon.edu.au 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh! This is what I was looking for! This works nicely, thank you!